# Find the domain of combined functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I have a question asking to find the domain of $g(f(x))$ given $f(x)=2x^2+x$, and $g(x)=x^2+1$.  I can easily do these questions in reverse when you have to find $f(g(x))$, but when having to find $g(f(x))$ I get a little mixed up.  Here is how I started:

$g(f(x))$

$=x(2x^2+x)^2+1$

$=2x^2+x(2x^2+x)+1$

But I am not sure if I have set this up properly.

If someone could help me through this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: In order to know the domain of the composition you must first know what the domains of the original functions are. Have these been given to you? Or are they assuming the domain and range to be real numbers?

Comment: @Sir Jective No this did not give them to me.  But judging by that they are both quadratic functions, I would think that their domain would be any real numbers (XER),  So then I need to determine the value of g(f(x) and get the domain of it.  I have already solved for f(g(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you just have to do one thing at a time. Here,

$g(f(x))$

$= g(2x^2 + x)$

$= (2x^2 + x)^2 + 1$

Just think of $g$ as a machine that takes its input, and outputs the input squared plus one.

Now, assuming that the domains of $f$ and $g$ are both $\mathbb{R}$, see if there are any real numbers $x$ for which the above expression creates a problem. If there are, those values are not part of the domain. If there are no such values, then the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: By looking at the graphs for these functions.  They all seem to have a parabola shape.  Including g(f(x).  Is the domain of g(f(x) xER as well (is any real numbers?).  Could this be coincidence? Since I know f(g(x) doesn't necessarily equal g(f(x)

Comment: Well, they'll look like parabolas, but they aren't polynomials of degree $2$. Since both $f$ and $g$ are machines that square their inputs before doing things to them, this parabolic-like shape is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

$g(f(x)) = g(2x^2+x) = (2x^2+x)^2+1 = (2x^2)^2 + 2(2x^2)x + x^2 + 1 = ....$ can you take it from here?

Comment: This should become $4x^4+x^2+1$ right? Or can this be simplified any further?

Comment: Could you please explain to me the third line of your answer: $(2x^2)^2+2(2x^2)x+x^2+1$.  I don't quite understand how you got that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple rule: the domain of all polynomial functions(a sum of positive powers of x) is all Real numbers unless you are told otherwise. Additionally the below also holds for polynomials:

1. They are continuous on R
2. They are differentiable on R

So when you see functions such as below, rejoice!

f(x)=-2x^2+x-7
f(x)=x^3/3-3x^2+0.755
f(x)=4x^4+3x-55